# What is the path to upload an image in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

new to java here.

I have a java project in netbeans 12.2 using javafx and I want to load an image from a resources folder into a javafx image object.

I have the following code:

```
Image image = new Image( "/resources/splash.jpg", 32, 32, false, true )
```

But I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found

So I think the path I'm trying to use is incorrect, can someone please help me find the correct path? My folder structure is as bellow

[image: my java project folder structure]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Image image = new Image("resources/splash.jpg", 32, 32, false, true)
```